# Supported method for changing CRM PartyLookup attribute from SystemUser in email from field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

When creating a new email under certain conditions I want to apply a lookup view to the from and to partylookup fields.

The reason being that certain email messages they (end user) want to come from X queue. To reduce mistakes and speed users we want to apply the proper queue lookup view thus presenting the proper choices right off.

For the "to" field this line works just fine:

```
//LookupViewId is a namespace variable set to the guid earlier in the script
Xrm.Page.getControl("to").setDefaultView(LookupViewId.ExternalReferralAgency);
```

However the "from" field is requiring a little more effort.

First the "from" is being set to the current user like Joe Schmoe. I handle that by setting it null.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("from").setValue(null);
```

However my lookup filter is not being applied.

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("from").setDefaultView(LookupViewId.ApprovedBatchResponse);
```

There is no error is just isn't being applied. Well this is because the defaulttype needs to be changed **however** I have yet to find a supported way of doing this.

I am using jquery to change the attribute but this isn't technically supported.

```
$("#from").attr("defaulttype", 2020); //unsupported hack for defaulttype of systemuser
Xrm.Page.getControl("from").setDefaultView(LookupViewId.ApprovedBatchResponse);
```

The risk is low of this being a problem but if possible I would still like to use a supported technique if possible.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried setting both default views as early in the page load as possible i.e. in the OnLoad function?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a "supported" way to do this, even, customizing the field, you cannot set up views to a party lookup.

Remember that "Unsupported" does not mean wrong. It can be perfectly legit and compatible but, if the code breaks someday, Microsoft will not give you support for that problem.

This is the risk, but I think is pretty simple to manage and fix the day it will no longer works.